# Query SQL,find the teams that do not have any athlete who reached the finish line of a flat stage first or second

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query that asks me to find the teams that do not have any athlete who reached the finish line of a flat stage first or second.

These are the tables:

- cyclist (cyclist_id: Int, name_cyclist: string, team: string of three letters, country: three-letter string)
- tape (_name: string, km: int, type: 'flat' or 'high_mountain' or 'medium_mountain' or 'chronometro_a_team' or 'chronometro_individual' or 'time_trial')
- arrival_order (cyclist_id:int ; tape_name:string, order: int): where cyclist_id (resp, tape_name) is an external key that refers to cyclist (resp, tape);

This is the script that I managed to do. The problem is that it returns me the name of a team if for example there are 2 athletes and one is ranked among the top 2 and the other is not. How can I solve this problem?

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.team
FROM arrival_order oa
JOIN tape s   ON oa.tape_name   = s.tape_name
JOIN cyclist c   ON oa.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id
WHERE oa.order>2 AND s.type='flat';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and do the check on `order` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT c.team
FROM arrival_order oa JOIN
     tape s
     ON oa.tape_name = s.tape_name JOIN
     cyclist c
     ON oa.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id
WHERE s.type = 'flat'
GROUP BY c.team
HAVING MIN(oa.order) > 2 ;
```

Comment: I tried but this error returns :
the "c.team" column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function ROW 1: SELECT c.Team

Comment: @Diolezzo . . . If I'm going to recommend aggregation, the answer should have a `GROUP BY`.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First, for proper normalization, there should be a table for teams.

```
CREATE TABLE teams AS SELECT DISTINCT team FROM cyclists;
ALTER TABLE teams ADD PRIMARY KEY (team);
```

Then table cyclists should refer to it by id and not name, but let's skip that.

> find the teams that do not have any athlete who reached the finish line of a flat stage first or second.

Well that sounds like a NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM teams
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM arrival_order
    JOIN cyclists ON (cyclists.id=arrival_order.cyclist_id)
    JOIN tape ON (tape.name=arrival_order.tape_name)
    WHERE arrival_order.order <= 2
     AND  tape.type = 'flat'
     AND  cyclists.team = team.name
)
```

You can also use a LEFT JOIN, but that would be more complicated, and postgres will probably turn your NOT EXISTS into a LEFT JOIN for optimization anyway.

Note if a team has no cyclists, or its cyclists did not participate in any flat races, the team will still be in the result... because that's what was asked in the question: "team does not have any athlete who reached the finish line of a flat stage first or second."

If you want to find the teams that have athletes who reached the finish line of a flat stage, but were not ranked first or second, then you should use a JOIN instead of a NOT EXIST, and put order>2 somewhere in the WHERE.